# How do I recover files that disappeared after wrong MV command format?

Tags: linux, busybox

I'm trying to move files from the current directory to another directory by date, but I accidentally used the wrong target format:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime +365 -type f -exec mv "{}" "..\folder" \;
```

instead of

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime +365 -type f -exec mv "{}" "../folder" \;
```

Then my files just disappeared.

I can't seem to find it anywhere. I've tried on both target & source directories and even the non existent directory that I have accidentally sent the files to.

I would just like to know if I can still recover the files.

Comment: short answer: they're gone for good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're all gone. When you run:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime +365 -type f -exec mv "{}" "..\folder" \;
```

You are executing, for every file, the command:

```
mv filename ..folder
```

In other words, you renamed every file to the name `..folder`. Each file overwrote the next one.  The contents of the `..folder` file are whatever file was last processed by your command, and all the rest are gone.

Comment: I figured that would have been the case. Thanks for the help.